# Javascript time and weekday/weekend CSS change

Tags: javascript, css, time

I am trying to make a script that will make the following happen:

- I need to change the color of an element on my page from green to red depending on the time of the day AND day of the week. So for example, on Saturday I need another time window than on Monday.

I am struggling to find something that works. I found several scripts that change the CSS depending on time, but I can't find a script that changes the CSS depending on time AND day. Is there a script somewhere that I can use?

Scripts I found that change the CSS depending on time:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/different-stylesheet-pending-the-time-of-day/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-time-based-css-style-sheet-switcher--net-22814

====

This is working for me (got some help from someone I know):

```
function getStylesheet() {
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
var currentDay = new Date().getDay();

document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/close.css'         
type='text/css'>");
   if (1 <= currentDay&&currentDay < 6){
   // mon/tue/wen/thu/fri
   if (8 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 18) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/open.css'    
   type='text/css'>");
} 
} else if (currentDay === 6) { 
  // Its Saturday
  if (10 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 17) {
  document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/open.css'     
  type='text/css'>");
  }     
 } 
}
getStylesheet();
```

Comment: You can get the day from [*date.getDay()*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.16). Sunday is 0, Saturday is 6. Also try [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Answer (score 1):

You need to incorporate the day into your script via `Date().getDay`. The code below expands upon the CSS-tricks example you linked to and should give you a starting point.

This code is untested and can be improved allot(You'll have a whole lot of if statements by the end)

Heres a working example of the code, substituting a simple output instead of swapping stylesheets - http://codepen.io/tonyedwardspz/pen/bVoprx?editors=101 (It will only work on Wednesdays in its current state, I didn't fancy writing all the if statements)

```
function getStylesheet() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
  var currentDay = new Date().getDay();

  if (currentDay === 0){
    // Its Sunday
    if (currentTime < 5) {
     document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>");
    }else if (currentTime < 11) {
     document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='morning.css' type='text/css'>");
    }else if (currentTime < 16) {
     document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='day.css' type='text/css'>");
    } else if (currentTime < 22) {
     document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='evening.css' type='text/css'>");
    }else if (currentTime <= 24) {
     document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>");
    }
  } else if (currentDay === 1){
    // Its Monday
  } else if (currentDay === 2){
    // Its Tuesday
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem. If this solves your question don't forget to mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Tried different things, but this script doesn't seem to work. I also tried the CSS Tricks script and that does work, but of course that's only for time and not day.

Comment: @NerdyBirdy When you say this code doesn't work, are you getting and error messages? Post the code your trying in you question.

Comment: what confused me was this part of the code. You declare times and then you also check the day, but you already checked that at the start of the first if statement ( currentDay === 0 ).

 && currentDay === 2) {

Sorry, I am still learning Javascript.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i'll update the code. I left the internal tests by mistake.

Comment: @NerdyBirdy - Its unrelated to your question, but I think that something like the following will help you in future javascript efforts - https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript

Comment: I am learning javascript through Codecademy, thanks. And maybe what I am trying to do is too hard for a beginner :(. 

Your updated code doesn't work either. There must be something wrong with the getDay-part of it, because the CSS Tricks code does work.

Comment: @NerdyBirdy Awesome, your on the right track with codecademy. I've updated my question with a working example of my code. Your issues must be somewhere else. If you share what you have tried based on my example (In your question) I'll help you get it working.

Comment: Thanks for your help @tonyedwardspz !  I had some help from someone I know and now I have a working script! I added it to my question.

Comment: Well done @NerdyBirdy, welcome to the world of Javascript :)